# Programmatically block screen saver in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

Is it possible to programatically ask Mac OS X not to turn on the screen saver while your application is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use:

```
UpdateSystemActivity(UsrActivity);
```

Here is [Apple's example code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1160.html).

Be aware this is deprecated for 64bit binaries, and I have not found a suitable replacement, but the [struggle continues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324814/what-is-the-cocoa-equivalent-of-updatesystemactivity).