# What is the correct way to prevent sleep on OS X?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically prevent a Mac from going to sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/how-to-programmatically-prevent-a-mac-from-going-to-sleep)

What is the correct method on the current version of OS X (10.7) for preventing sleep while an application or process is running?

In particular, is `IOCancelPowerChange` still (or did it ever) serve this purpose? I call `IOCancelPowerChange` in response to `kIOMessageCanSystemSleep`, but that doesn't do the trick.

---

Essentially the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/how-to-programmatically-prevent-a-mac-from-going-to-sleep) as the first part of this one has been asked before, but the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1160/_in) it points to is quite old and the answer was never accepted.

Comment: There's a [new Apple Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) on this.

Comment: @Michael: And I'd like to do the same. Is there a way I can amend the question?

Comment: Posting a bounty will raise that question's visibility, and may prompt more answers. Click the `start a bounty` link on that question, and provide the resulting dialog with your reasons for wanting a more current answer. Add a comment if you want to provide more detail.

Comment: @rax: Anybody can propose an edit to a post. Your specific query about `IOCancelPowerChange` could probably stand on its own, if you want it to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`IOCancelPowerChange` continues to work but only for idle triggered sleep; it will not work for sleep triggered by the Finder's Sleep menu item, programmatically requested, or from a push of the power button.

Apple's [Q&A1340](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) answers the question "Q: How can my application get notified when the computer is going to sleep or waking from sleep? How do I prevent sleep?"

Listing 2 of [Q&A1340](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html):

```
#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>

// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep prevents display sleep,
// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep prevents idle sleep

//reasonForActivity is a descriptive string used by the system whenever it needs 
//  to tell the user why the system is not sleeping. For example, 
//  "Mail Compacting Mailboxes" would be a useful string.

//  NOTE: IOPMAssertionCreateWithName limits the string to 128 characters. 
CFStringRef* reasonForActivity= CFSTR("Describe Activity Type");

IOPMAssertionID assertionID;
IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep, 
                                    kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, reasonForActivity, &assertionID); 
if (success == kIOReturnSuccess)
{

    //Add the work you need to do without 
    //  the system sleeping here.

    success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
    //The system will be able to sleep again. 
}
```

Note that you can only stop idle time sleep, not sleep triggered by the user.

For applications supporting Mac OS X 10.6 and later, use the new **IOPMAssertion** family of functions. These functions allow other applications and utilities to see your application's desire not to sleep; this is critical to working seamlessly with third party power management software.

Answer (score -2):

You could call updatesystemActivity(OverallAct) every 30 seconds to prevent the display from sleeping.

Comment: Please avoid this trick. Instead use the Apple endorsed techniques documented in Q&A1340.

Comment: How come? Apple advises this method in a document too.

Comment: Apple's latest recommendation in Q&A1340 is to use the new IOPMAssertionCreateWithName interface. This interface avoids your application needing to demand CPU cycles every 30 seconds, it provides a simplified way for Mac OS X – and other tools – to check for assertions, and better indicates your applications real intention. Telling the system to mimic user activity every 30 seconds is a trick that worked but has now been superseded by a formal API.