# How to access iokit/pwr_mgt from swift?

Tags: macos, swift, power-management

I'm trying to write an OSX app (**not iOS**) that prevents the system from going to sleep when certain things are happening. To do so, I'm trying to access the `pwr_mgt` submodule of IOKit from a MacOS app using Swift.

In XCode, I've indicated that I want to use the IOKit framework, and in code, I'm have declared `import IOKit`. Although IOKit's classes/methods import fine (I can see them with auto-complete when I type IO*Whatever), the ones relating to power management don't show up.

I've tried to instead `import IOKit.pwr_mgt`, but the compiler complains that the submodule can't be found.

`<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'pwr_mgt'`

From [other documentation for how to do this with Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460033/what-is-the-correct-way-to-prevent-sleep-on-os-x), the classes that I need to access (amongst others) are:

- `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName`
- `IOPMAssertionID`
- `IOPMAssertionRelease`
- `CFStringRef`
- `CFSTR`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a solution to this problem in older Xcode betas, but on Beta 7 (and I imagine in Xcode 6.1 too)

```
import IOKit.pwr_mgt
```

works fine in newer betas.

Comment: Yes, at least it imports now.

Comment: How do you know the name of the module is `pwr_mgt`? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/iokit/1557076-iopmschedulepowerevent) don't reference this.