# Programmatically wake display on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, wakeup

I've managed to get the display to sleep immediately with

```
pmset displaysleepnow
```

in terminal, however for waking the display I've only found

```
pmset schedule wake "12/24/2009 00:00:00"
```

which fails to work if I try to schedule anything earlier than at least 10secs from now.

Is there any way to programmatically wake the display in Cocoa? Someone has suggested IOPMAssertionDeclareUserActivity but I couldn't find any examples on this so I am struggling.

I am using Swift by the way, but Objective C code is also welcome.

Comment: Perhaps try exploiting the "wake on network activity" feature. I think it's more commonly known as "Wake on LAN".

Comment: what *exactly* are you trying to wake the display programmatically for? I dont see a point in waking a display when a user isn't present.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315685/how-to-wake-from-sleep-programmatically)? The first answer seems relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wake from display sleep in OSX 10.7.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598809/how-do-i-wake-from-display-sleep-in-osx-10-7-4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
  IOPMAssertionID assertionID; 
  IOPMAssertionDeclareUserActivity(CFSTR(""), kIOPMUserActiveLocal, &assertionID);
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer so people can easily find the solution.

Comment: This code was working fine till OSX 10.10 but does not seem to work on OSX El Capitan. Do we have an alternative?

Comment: I didn't know, haven't upgraded yet. Please post a solution here if you find one

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer in Swift 3.x:

```
var assertionID : IOPMAssertionID = 0
 _ = IOPMAssertionDeclareUserActivity("" as CFString, kIOPMUserActiveLocal, &assertionID)
```

Comment: thanks, - but for anyone else who's trying this - took me half an hour to discover you find the import you need (which is IOKit.pwr_mgt) to get the above function