# How to make the display sleep and wake

Tags: applescript

There is a problem with the backlight of my mac. Sometimes when I turn it on the backlight does not come on. However if I manually force the screen to sleep and wake a couple of times it does light up. So I want to write an applescript to automate this process.
I have looked at ...
[How do I wake from display sleep in OSX 10.7.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598809/how-do-i-wake-from-display-sleep-in-osx-10-7-4)
But that is not written in Applescript (or if it is I cannot figure out how to run it.

I have tried the following

```
do shell script "pmset displaysleepnow"
tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
end tell
do shell script "pmset displaysleepnow"
tell application "Google Chrome"
quit
end tell
```

But the screen blanks and never relights. I have also tried using caffeine as per some questions about this. I have tried using code to move the mouse and/or click the mouse programmatically.

If I just run the displaysleepnow followed by the 'activate chrome' that works, but if the displaysleepnow is executed again nothing appears to reactivate it.

I am using macOS 10.14.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Synopsis

One way to approach this is to:

1. Obtain the current date/time plus *x* number of seconds in the future.
2. Schedule the system/display to *"wake"* in the future using the date/time obtained at point 1.
3. Then set your display to sleep.

#### Solution

Consider utilizing the following AppleScript to meet your requirement:

```
set wakeAfterSeconds to "15"
set myPassword to "xxxxxxxxxx"

set now to do shell script "date -r $(date +%s) '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'"

set wakeTime to do shell script "date -jv +" & wakeAfterSeconds & "S -f " & ¬
  quoted form of "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S" & " " & quoted form of now & " " & ¬
  quoted form of "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"

do shell script "pmset schedule wake " & quoted form of wakeTime & ¬
  " && pmset displaysleepnow" password myPassword with administrator privileges
```

#### Code Explanation

1. The line that reads;

   ```
   set now to do shell script "date -r $(date +%s) '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'"
   ```

   essentially executes the following bash [`date`](https://ss64.com/osx/date.html) command, using the Applescript [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command, to obtain the current date/time:

   ```sh
   $ date -r $(date +%s) '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
   ```

   This assigns the current date/time, formatted as `MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS`, to the variable named `now`.
2. The lines reading;

   ```
   set wakeTime to do shell script "date -jv +" & wakeAfterSeconds & "S -f " & ¬
     quoted form of "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S" & " " & quoted form of now & " " & ¬
     quoted form of "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
   ```

   obtain a future date/time by adding *x* no. of seconds to the current date/time (i.e. it adds 15 seconds). This future date/time, (which again is computed using the shells `date` utility), is assigned to the variable named `wakeTime`.
3. The lines that read:

   ```
   do shell script "pmset schedule wake " & quoted form of wakeTime & ¬
     " && pmset displaysleepnow" password myPassword with administrator privileges
   ```

   utilize the [`pmset`](https://ss64.com/osx/pmset.html) utility to perform the following two tasks:

   - Schedules the display to *"wake"* at a future date/time, i.e. after 15 seconds.
   - Sets the system to *"sleep"* now.

#### Additional notes:

1. You'll need to set the no. of seconds assigned to the `wakeAfterSeconds` variable to a value which is appropriate for your system. You may find that you need to increase, or decrease, this value.

   *In essence the number of seconds that you set the `wakeAfterSeconds` value to must be longer than the number of seconds it takes for your display to enter sleep mode - it's got to be asleep before it can be woken !*
2. Setting a shedule to wake your computer using the `pmset` utility must be run as root, therefore it requires your password. So you'll need to set the value of the `myPassword` variable as necessary.
3. You mentioned;

   > ... if I manually force the screen to sleep and wake **a couple of times** it does light up.

   In which case you may want to consider wrapping the aforementioned code in a [`repeat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362) statement.

   For instance, the following repeats the process twice:

   ```
   set wakeAfterSeconds to "15"
   set myPassword to "xxxxxxxxxx"

   repeat 2 times
     set now to do shell script "date -r $(date +%s) '+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'"

     set wakeTime to do shell script "date -jv +" & wakeAfterSeconds & "S -f " & ¬
       quoted form of "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S" & " " & quoted form of now & " " & ¬
       quoted form of "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"

     do shell script "pmset schedule wake " & quoted form of wakeTime & ¬
       " && pmset displaysleepnow" password myPassword with administrator privileges

     delay wakeAfterSeconds
   end repeat
   ```

   **Utilize *"Login Items"* to auto run the application:**

   Also, you may want to consider adding the aforementioned AppleScript application to your *Login Items*. This would automatically run the application when you start-up your computer. To do this:

   1. Firstly ensure the scripts *"File Format"* has been saved as an "Application" via your AppleScript Editor.
   2. Launch *"System Preferences"* and select *"Users & Groups"*.
   3. Select your user account in the panel on the left side, and click *"Login Items"*
   4. Click the plus icon `+` and select the AppleScript Application.
   5. Relaunch your computer.

   [image]

#### Older Mac OSX:

On older versions of macOS (namely OSX) the `pmset` utility did not include a `displaysleepnow` command. It just had the `pmset sleepnow` command. So, for those wanting to run this on older OSX you'll need to change the last `do shell script` command to:

```
do shell script "pmset schedule wake " & quoted form of wakeTime & ¬
  " && pmset sleepnow" password myPassword with administrator privileges
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Fabulous answer works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: btw do you happen to know why my approach didn't work?