# How can I monitor the screen lock status on macOS

Tags: c++, macos

I'm working on a cli password manager with C++ on macOS, and now I need to do something after the screen being locked, such as cleanup credential which displayed on screen.

Is there any ideal about that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use these answers [How to programmatically prevent a Mac from going to sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/), adopt them to your needs instead of preventing the sleep.

Comment: screen lock and sleep are different features entirely